# How can classes call methods to each other?

Tags: java, oop, event-handling

I have 2 classes, a Login panel and GUI panel. The code below states that when I log-in, it would show my GUI and hide my Login. And at some time it has to recall that Login panel again when the log-out button is clicked. The code below results in a StackOverFlow error. I know what that error means but I don't know how I could fix it. Is there any better solution for calling such methods from another class when that "another class" has to call something too on the class that has called it?

```
//Login Panel
public class MyPanel1 extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    MyPanel2 p2 = new MyPanel2();
    .
    .
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
           //if login is a success
             setVisible(false);
             p2.setVisible(true);  
    }
}
```

```
//GUI Panel
public class MyPanel2 extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
   MyPanel1 p1 = new MyPanel1();
   .
   .
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
          //if logout button is clicked
            setVisible(false);
            p1.setVisible(true);  
   }
}
```

My stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at sun.awt.Win32GraphicsConfig.getBounds(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.Win32GraphicsConfig.getBounds(Win32GraphicsConfig.java:222)
    at java.awt.Window.init(Window.java:505)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:537)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:385)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:189)
    at Login.<init>(Login.java:29)
    at Cashier.<init>(Cashier.java:10)
    at Login.<init>(Login.java:9)
    at Cashier.<init>(Cashier.java:10)
    at Login.<init>(Login.java:9)
    at Cashier.<init>(Cashier.java:10)
    at Login.<init>(Login.java:9)
```

Comment: you should avoid such a circular dependencies... instead google about callbacks!

Comment: Can you post your stack trace please?

Comment: See my edited post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass a reference of the first panel to the constructor of the second panel.

```
//Login Panel
public class MyPanel1 extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    MyPanel2 p2 = new MyPanel2(this);
    .
    .
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
       //if login is a success
         setVisible(false);
         p2.setVisible(true);  
    }
} 

//GUI Panel
public class MyPanel2 extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
   MyPanel1 p1;
   public MyPanel2(MyPanel1 parent){
       this.p1 = parent;
   }
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
      //if logout button is clicked
        setVisible(false);
        p1.setVisible(true);  
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you further explain this? Im quite pretty confused but I'm getting the idea. OOP is still new to me.

Comment: @Wingzero is there anything specific that you don't understand? I'm not so good at explaining and knowing what you want to know would make it easier for me.